# Swift: Is there a better way to add data to a dictionary that's a function parameter?

Tags: swift

I am passing a dictionary into a function, then add some data to this dictionary and pass it to another function again:

```
f(["initial": "initial"])

func f(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    var mutatingDictionary = dictionary
    mutatingDictionary["test"] = "test"
    anotherFunction(mutatingDictionary)
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a better or more elegant way to do this, without having to write 3 lines, and maybe a better way to handle the variable (like not having to recreate a `mutatingDictionary`) ?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place.

Comment: @vahdet I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[merging(_:uniquingKeysWith:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127173-merging) will give you a new copy without mutability.  The uniquing parameter makes it verbose though.  I suppose if it bothers you, you can make your own dictionary extension called `merging` that will just always supply a take left function for uniquing:

```
f(["initial": "initial"])

func f(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    anotherFunction(dictionary.merging(["test":"test"], uniquingKeysWith: { left, _ in left}))
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I'm going to follow this advice and make an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inout as parameter and same dictionary can be mutated and can be used throughout the viewController

```
var yourDictionary: [String: Any] = ["initial": "initial"]

func f(_ dictionary: inout [String: Any]) {
    dictionary["test"] = "test"
    anotherFunction(&dictionary)
}

func anotherFunction(_ dictionary: inout [String: Any]) {
    dictionary["moreKey"] = "moreValue"
}

f(&yourDictionary)
print(yourDictionary)
```

It will prints

```
["initial": "initial", "moreKey": "moreValue", "test": "test"]
```

May be this is something you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I thought about `inout`, but in the end I think I'll follow Josh Homann idea and create an extension for this.